# Can I use onpopstate with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-history

I'm currently (happily) using jquery to bind a ajax request function to the window.onpopstate event in non-IE browsers.  However, IE never hits my `doAjax` function.

```
    // Bind a function to the popstate event to execute ajax requests
    // this allows request to occur on back/fwd browser navigation 
    window.onpopstate = doAjax;
```

Anyone know if there's a way to make IE 8/9 play nice somehow?

Comment: I think `pushState` or `replaceState` functions can trigger this event. When do you expect IE will trigger this event?

Comment: `pushState` / `onpopstate` are not supported on IE < 10.

Comment: @Václav: I'm using the History jquery library to update the url on new ajax page loads. My goal is to fire an ajax page load event any time the url changes so that a user can return to the previous ajax 'page' when they click the back button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I have arrived at is to bind both `onpopstate` and `onhashchange` to the desired handler.

```
    // Popstate: load ajax
    window.onpopstate = handlePageWipe;

    // And onhashchange for IE
    if( jQuery.browser.msie ) window.onhashchange = handlePageWipe;
```

I am using the History jquery library to update the url as I make ajax changes to the page.  Unfortunately, and predictably, IE hasn't caught up and there seems to be no way to alter the url with JS.  History falls back to updating the url's hash state in IE, so this serves my initial goal of binding a url state change to a handler in IE.

Of course this opens up another can of worms because I now have to handle both url changes and hash changes.  Ah well, so it goes...

**EDIT:**
As @linus points out, we should be charitable and avoid browser detection to give IE an opportunity for reform.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to do like this:

```
if (window.onpopstate != undefined) {
    window.onpopstate = locate;
} else {
    window.onhashchange = locate;
}
```

so if "msie" add this functionality you do not depend on old code

Comment: actually it should be window.onpopstate !== undefined

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a project that uses **jQuery history plugin**, copyrighted by Takayuki Miwa. The client code initialises the library with `$.history.init(callback, ...)`.
That callback is invoked each time you navigate to/refresh the page, and also each time the page content is updated by means of AJAX, whether for clicks, history back, history forward.

If you are using that same library, you could do the same in order to have code invoked when page content changes, thus dropping the onpopstate/onhashchange thing.

If you are using the more recent [**History.js** from B A Lupton](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) plugin, there's a `statechange` event you can bind to.

Also, bear in mind that even `onhashchange` is supported "only" from IE8.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

this solved me:

if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie ') )
    window.onhashchange = locate
else 
    window.onpopstate = locate