# How can I have perfect stats with onclick on Google Analytics?

Tags: hash, onclick, google-analytics, statistics, href

When I'm naviguating with the arrows "Previous/Next" on my Gallery, Google Analytics counts the previous picture (containing hash).

To be clear here an example :

> **www.example.com/gallery.html#title_1**
>
> *Next*
>
> **www.example.com/gallery.html#title_2**
>
> *Next*
>
> **www.example.com/gallery.html#title_3**
>
> Google Analytics counts in this example : 1 view for title_1 ... 1
>   view for title_2 while I'm on the title_3

Here my Google Analtytics tracking code that I put on the arrows :

```
<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);" class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>
<a href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);" class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>
```

Any idea ?
Hope you will help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is pretty clear. You are firing the pageview before the url changes, while you expect it to be fired after the hash changes on the url. There are 2 options here.

You can either introduce a timer, so the pageview is fired a couple miliseconds after the click. This should allow the hash to change before the pageview. It's a little bit dirty but should do the job. Something like this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);
}, 200);
```

Another option is to use window.onpopstate and forget about the clicks on the arrows Next/Prev.

```
window.onpopstate = function(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);
}
```

Read more about popstate to see other options that do the same but may provide some better support accross-browsers.

eg:

[Can I use onpopstate with IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232745/can-i-use-onpopstate-with-ie)